# Error: I want remove <option selected=""></option> tag, it auto add when get records from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have a table:

```
id | name 
__________ 
1  | cat 1
2  | cat 2
3  | cat 3
4  | cat 4
```

Controllers:

```
$this->load->model('admin/mcategories');
$data['cat'] = $this->mcategories->list_cat();
$this->load->view('admin/myform', $data);
```

views :

```
foreach($cat as $key => $value1) {
    echo "<option value='$value1[id]'>$value1[name]</option>";
}
```

when I get records from database, my result is:

```
<select name="cat">    
  <option value="1">cat 1</option>
  <option value="2">cat 2</option>
  <option value="3">cat 3</option>
  <option value="4">cat 4</option>
  <option selected=""></option>
```

I want remove 
    `<option selected=""></option>`.

I use codeigniter.

Comment: can you post the entire code..

Comment: I have a feeling Codeigniter is gonna be way too advanced for you.

Comment: please put entire code

Answer (score 0):

Your view should be:

```
<select class="form-control">
            <?php 

            foreach($groups as $row)
            { 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `$options` is the result from your db,

```
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );
```

Then you could add the empty option and set it as selected as below:

```
 $options[' '] = '';
 $selected = array(' ');
 echo form_dropdown('test', $options, $selected);
```

Comment: Thank's, but i want remove tag <option selected=""></option>. I use foreach to get data from controllers and show it on views. ex: `foreach($cat as $key => $value1) {
echo "<option value='$value1[id]'>$value1[name]</option>";`. Sr, my english it not good.